# How do I show user attributes on articles?

Tags: nodes, users, entities

I added a custom field "Twitter URL" to each of my users (on the page Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings). I'm trying to display this "Twitter URL" on every article that that user makes. For example, under the "Published by someusername on Wed, 12/28/2011 - 02:57" that is already on every post, I want to have the "Twitter URL" for that user right under that.

> Published by mike on Wed, 12/28/2011 - 02:57
>   http://twitter.com/someusername

I think I need to go into node.tlp.php and edit something, but could anyone give me a little more help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at [`node.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/7), you'll notice there's already a variable for this type of data: `$submitted`. You could replace that variable with your own data, but to do it the Drupal way, what you want to do is modify the value of `$submitted` using a preprocess function.

In your theme, create a `template.php` file (if you don't have one already). In it, add the following function (replacing `example` with the short name of your theme):

```
function example_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Linkify the URL
  $twitter_url = l('http://twitter.com/someusername', 'http://twitter.com/someusername');

  // This is the same thing as saying 
  // $variables['submitted'] = $variables['submitted'] . ' ' . $twitter_url;
  $variables['submitted'] .= ' ' . $twitter_url;
}
```

Clear the cache (*Configuration* → Performance → *Clear cache*), and check your node pages again: you should see the Twitter URL appended to submitted line.

But this is of course, static: to load the user's Twitter URL, you'll need to load the field data:

```
function example_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Even though there's a user object in $variables['user'], we need to
  // load a new copy because the preloaded one doesn't have have field data
  $user = user_load($variables['uid']);

  // Retrieve the data and its value for the Twitter URL field
  // Replace field_twitter_url with the short name of the field
  // found at admin/config/people/accounts/fields
  $items = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_twitter_url');
  $field = field_view_value('user', $user, 'field_twitter_url', $items[0]);

  // Get the rendered output of the field for use in the submitted line
  $twitter_url = drupal_render($field));

  // If you wanted to get more fields, repeat the last three lines, replacing
  // field_twitter_url with the names of the other fields.

  // Linkify the URL and append it to the $submitted variable
  $variables['submitted'] .= ' ' . l($twitter_url, $twitter_url);
}
```

The Field API isn't the most intuitive or straightforward API in the world, but here's what's going on:

1. Load the user object, which contains the information about the fields attached to it.
2. Load the specific data associated with the `field_twitter_url` using [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7).
3. Get the render array for the specific field you want to display using [`field_view_value()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_value/7).
4. Get the final rendered output using [`drupal_render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7).

Now, if you wanted to have the Twitter URL separate (so you can move it to where ever you want in the template), just create your own variable:

```
function example_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
   // ...
   // Do all the stuff from the previous sample function, except
   // setting $variables['submitted']
   // ...

   $variables['twitter_url'] = $twitter_url;
}
```

Now, you can add `$twitter_url` to anywhere in `node.tpl.php`. If your theme doesn't already have its own `node.tpl.php`, navigate to the `modules/node` folder, copy the `node.tpl.php` that's there to your theme folder, and clear the cache.

Comment: I don't have time to try this until tonight but this sounds like exactly what I need. One question though. Lets say I have multiple fields (i.e. field_twitter_url, field_fb_url, and field_something) what would I change? Would it be possible for you to edit the answer to show this case?

Comment: @Mike Added, but all you need to do is repeat steps 2-4 with the Field API (`field_get_items()`, `field_view_value()`, then `drupal_render()`) with the other field names.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. I was wondering if you could take a look at this question I posted and give me some feedback. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18480/cant-show-custom-user-field-on-nodes

Comment: or is there a module to take care of this?