# Can't show custom user field on nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, users

This is a follow up question to: [How do I show user attributes on articles?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18392/how-do-i-show-user-attributes-on-articles)

I still can't get the "Twitter URL" field to show up on articles, and got tired of reading through the Fields API docs; I figured I couldd ask if anyone can look at my template files, and tell me why the twitter URL is not output, as I know it is being set.

This is the node preprocess function from node.tpl.php:

```
function blogbuzz_preprocess_node(&$vars, &$variables) {
  if ($vars['view_mode'] != 'full' && $vars['id'] == 1) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'node-first';
  }

  if ($vars['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($vars['node'])) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'node-full';

  }
  // Even though there's a user object in $variables['user'], we need to
  // load a new copy because the preloaded one doesn't have have field data
  $user = user_load($variables['uid']);

  // Retrieve the data and its value for the Twitter URL field
  // Replace field_twitter_url with the short name of the field
  // found at admin/config/people/accounts/fields
  $items = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_twitter_url');
  $field = field_view_value('user', $user, 'field_twitter_url', $items[0]);

  // Get the rendered output of the field for use in the submitted line
  $twitter_url = drupal_render($field);

  // If you wanted to get more fields, repeat the last three lines, replacing
  // field_twitter_url with the names of the other fields.
  $variables['twitter_url'] = $twitter_url;
}
```

And here is  the template.tpl where I use `$twitter_url`:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
  <div class="node-inner clearfix">
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <?php if (!$page): ?>
      <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

    <div class="meta">
      <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
        <?php print t('Published by '); ?><?php print $name.t(' on ').$date; ?>
         <?php print t('Twitter '); ?><?php print $twitter_url; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if (!empty($content['field_tags'])): ?>
        <?php print ' in '.render($content['field_tags']);  ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
    <div class="content clearfix">
    <?php
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      hide($content['field_tags']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($content['links']): ?>
      <div class="extra-links">
        <?php if (!$page): ?>
          <div class="read-more"><?php print l(t('Read more'), 'node/' . $nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => t('node-readmore-link')))); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php print render($content['links']); ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
  </div>
</div> <!-- /node-inner, /node -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render the twitter_url twice. First in then preprocess function and then again in the template.

If that's not the problem, start debugging. Install devel.module if you haven't already and add dpm($variable) statements on the relevant places, e.g. dpm($twitter_url) in the preprocess function.

Comment: is there a module that could take care of this?

Comment: take care of what? You can't tell a module to debug your code. But there is the mentioned devel module that provides functions to assist you.

Comment: sorry, i should have specified. Is there a module to take care of showing fields I've added to users under the nodes that they make?

Comment: No, I don't think so. That's something that would be hard to configure, how and where should they be displayed and so on...